# How to store git login+password for particular repository?

Tags: git

I have several git repositories for different projects. Different projects have different login+password pairs for me. I want to store my credentials there (per repository, inside `projectN/.git/config`).

```
git config --local user.name "myusername"
git config --local user.email "myusername@myemaildomain.com"
git config --local  credential.helper ???
```

I use
Windows 7,

```
$ git --version
git version 2.11.0.windows.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Download Git for Windows, it has the [Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) intergrated. It will securely store your credentials in thw Windows Password Store.